# Unable to add or update Azure AD application

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to plug **Azure AD Authentication** to my MVC project.
and each time I try to connect the service these errors appear to me.
I checked the previous authentication into "packages.config" -"Web.config" and everything is clear.
also, I checked the client id, clientSecret, Redirect URL, Azure Domain and everything was right!!

**what's is the problem here so I can't move forward with it?**

[image: this appear after insert clientSecret]

[image: permission in the azure AD]

Comment: Do you have permissions on the AD to create the Application?

Comment: the Application already exists.

Comment: Please make it as the answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this kind of service linking Azure AD with needs permissions more that User.Read ,
because maybe it will change something in the Azure AD App.
so I change the project to authorize directly to Azure AD without that Service by edit the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that were adding `Read directory data` permission to the application. So you must have checked the permission when configure Azure AD Authentication.

[image]

Try to login Azure portal with the account which you used to configure Azure AD Authentication in Visual Studio. Find your application and check if you can add `Directory.Read.All` permission successfully.

[image]

If you can add it successfully, try to create a new Azure AD application when configure Azure AD Authentication.

[image]

Comment: thank you, yeah I did check the Read directory data to move forward since I began,  and for making new AD and give it read all, I can't for security reason, I do not think that this is the problem because I was reading the permission details for User. Read , it allow the App to sign in, and this is what i need to more.

Comment: @AzizAlzayed If you don't check `Read directory data` and create a new ad application, will this issue exist?

Comment: actually I can't remove it, it forces me to put it. I mean I cannot uncheck the box .

Comment: @AzizAlzayed I mean to create a new application. Click `configure Azure AD Authentication` and check `Create a new Azure AD application`. Then click 'Next' and don't check `Read directory data`.

Comment: yes lady, it's the same what I have here, both ways force me to make that. I mean I cannot uncheck it.

Comment: @AzizAlzayed You need to close the authentication window. Then open it again,

Comment: If you can't uncheck the _Read directory data_ box, try removing this line from your .csproj file and reloading the project: `<WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>1</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>`